# ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError after switching DB cluster node

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-cluster

**Environment**

I have a rails 3.2.x app load balanced between 2 webservers: web1 and web2. Each webserver points to a clustered IP for the mysql database. The database is 2 servers clustered (by rackspace). 1 database is active at a time until failover.

**Error**

On our latest failover web1 started sending `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` on `Middleware/Rack/ActiveRecord::QueryCache#call` (stack trace below) while web2 had no errors. Note, this occurred after the DB was stable and 100% switched to the other node.

**Theory**

My theory is that the session or cache or connection referenced the old node and once switched it could not find said connection. This does seem odd since both DB nodes are clustered, serving on the same clustered IP and are replicated.

**Temporary solution**

Our interim solution was to restart web1 rails server, this worked.

**Questions**

1) I was wondering if I could get an explanation of what might be happening here

2) Is there a configuration setting that could prevent this in the future.

**Stack Trace**

Error message
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds (waited 5.000268907 seconds). The max pool size is currently 5; consider increasing it.

…record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb: 258:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
…record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb: 242:in`loop'
…record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb: 242:in `block in checkout'
                   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb: 211:in`mon_synchronize'
…record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb: 239:in `checkout'
…record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb: 102:in`block in connection'
                   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb: 211:in `mon_synchronize'
…record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb: 101:in`connection'
…record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb: 410:in `retrieve_connection'
…nnection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb: 171:in`retrieve_connection'
…nnection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb: 145:in `connection'
…s/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:  67:in`rescue in call'
…s/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:  61:in `call'
…record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb: 479:in`call'
…ack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:  28:in `block in call'
…s/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb: 405:in`_run__862588711471957735__call__1324336831638990183__callbacks'
…s/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb: 405:in `__run_callback'
…s/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb: 385:in`_run_call_callbacks'
…s/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:  81:in `run_callbacks'
…ack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:  27:in`call'
…ack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:  31:in `call'
…/gems/airbrake-3.1.14/lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:  13:in`call'
….19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:  16:in `call'
…2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:  56:in`call'
…by/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:  32:in `call_app'
…by/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:  16:in`block in call'
…ivesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:  22:in `tagged'
…by/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:  16:in`call'
…ck-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:  22:in `call'
…/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:  21:in`call'
…/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:  17:in `call'
…9.1/gems/airbrake-3.1.14/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:  16:in`_call'
…9.1/gems/airbrake-3.1.14/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:  12:in `call'
…le/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb: 484:in`call'
…by/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb: 231:in `call'
…gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:  30:in`method_missing'
…r-3.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:  96:in `process_request'

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what was wrong? I'm getting the exact same errors on Heroku periodically, so wondering what triggers it.

Comment: not yet, I'm leaning toward something related to ActiveRecord caching, pooling, or sessions. I don't understand ActiveRecord connections enough yet to explore these however

Comment: Did you guys ever managed to figure it what was happening and how to fix it?

Comment: no solution. You could try to automate the web server restart when after you switch clusters.